# Read content of Json files in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hi i am trying to read contents of multiple json files in iterative fashion in terraform. But i am getting an jsondecode failed error.

**Policy.json** - A typical json file looks like below. I have similar files under a "alt" folder

```
{

    "displayName": "Airflow-Alert",

    "combiner": "OR",

    "conditions": [

        {

            "displayName": "Composer-Disk",

            "conditionThreshold": {

                "aggregations": [

                    {

                        "alignmentPeriod": "300s",

                        "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_NONE",

                        "groupByFields": [

                            "project_id"

                        ],

                        "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"

                    }

                ],

                "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",

                "duration": "0s",

                "filter": "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND resource.labels.project_id = \"prj-airflow-01\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/database/disk/bytes_used\"",

                "thresholdValue": 1600000000,

                "trigger": {

                    "count": 1

                }

            }

        }

    ]

}
```

**Alert.tf**

```
locals                                  {

  alert_jsons                           =  fileset(path.module, "alt/*.json")

  alert_data                            = [for f in local.alert_jsons : jsondecode(file("${f}")) ]

}
```

The error i am getting is :

```
on alert.tf line 80, in locals:
│   80:   alert_data                            = [for f in local.alert_jsons : jsondecode(file("${f}"))]
│ 
│ Call to function "jsondecode" failed: EOF.
```

Can someone point out what could be the issue. Thanks !

Comment: The error shows different code that in your question. Please make sure that the error matches your code in question.

Comment: Made the change. thanks for correcting

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. How many json files do you have? One of them is probably wrong.